# SWT double-click expansion

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I have implemented a double click listener on a tree viewer and my example code snippet is below.

```
private class DoubleClickListener implements IDoubleClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void doubleClick(final DoubleClickEvent event)
    {
        final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();
        if (selection == null || selection.isEmpty())
            return;

        final Object sel = selection.getFirstElement();

        final ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider)treeViewer.getContentProvider();

        if (!provider.hasChildren(sel))
              return;

        if (treeViewer.getExpandedState(sel))
            treeViewer.collapseToLevel(sel, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
        else
            treeViewer.expandToLevel(sel, 1);
    }
}
```

I have an issue now. I pass the tree viewer's object from different classes which needs double click functionality. So instead of passing tree viewer's object from different classes is there a way I could use `event.getSource()` which returns the object on which the event occurred? I tried implementing it but in vain. Can someone please suggest on how to proceed? I do not want to use tree viewer's object everywhere because `event.getSource()` returns the respective tree viewer's object.

**UPDATE**

Yes I agree to your point but I do not want to pass tree viewer as a parameter. So I have implemented it this way:

```
public class doubleClickListener implements IDoubleClickListener
{
    public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) 
    {
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        if (obj instanceof TreeViewer) 
        {
            TreeViewer eventSrc = (TreeViewer) obj;
            ITreeSelection selec = (ITreeSelection) eventSrc.getSelection();
            if (selec != null && !selec.isEmpty() && selec instanceof IStructuredSelection) 
            {
                IStructuredSelection selection = selec;
                Object item = selection.getFirstElement();              
                if (eventSrc.getExpandedState(item)) 
                {
                    eventSrc.collapseToLevel(item, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    eventSrc.expandToLevel(item, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an enhancement to my above code? I mean is creating an object of `ITreeSelection` and checking that object is an instaceof `IStructuredSelection` the right way to do? If not what could be the right way to check instanceof `IStructuredSelection`?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the tree viewer as a parameter to the double click constructor:

```java
public class DoubleClickListener implements IDoubleClickListener
{
   // The tree viewer to work with
   private final TreeViewer treeViewer;


   public DoubleClickListener(TreeViewer viewer)
   {
     treeViewer = viwer;
   }

   ... no change needed to doubleClick code
}
```

To use:

```java
treeViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new DoubleClickListener(treeViewer));
```

Update:

Alternatively the `DoubleClickEvent` `getSource()` method will be the `TreeViewer` (as long as the the listener is installed on a tree viewer!).

Comment: As I could not answer my question before 8 hours of posting it, I have edited my question and added my code there. Can you please look into it at the earliest?

Comment: Ok I will add my answer after 8 hours. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do I need this check selec!=null && !selec.isEmpty() ? If not then if null is passed how will it be handled?

Comment: You would have to read the code of the tree viewer to be sure if it every passes in null or an empty selection.